# Can data be lost when using NSInMemoryStoreType in CoreData?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

In CoreData when using a NSInMemoryStoreType persistent store, does the data stay cached in memory as long as the app is open, or is it possible that the resources being used by this data can be reclaimed by iOS?

Given that an iphone app can be backgrounded when multitasking, and that iOS will reclaim resources for apps that are running in the background.

Does this mean that the persistent stores in memory cache can be lost in some cases? Say perhaps if the app has been left in a background state for a long time, and the user has since visited and used a number of different apps.

If anyone can shed some light on this subject that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible that some of the resources inside of Core Data are `NSPurgeableData` objects, and so they might be dropped while you're suspended if there's memory pressure. This is an internal implementation detail, and should always be transparent to you.

As a concrete example outside of Core Data, `UIImage` is documented to drop some of its cached data when memory is tight (see Images and Memory Management in the `UIImage` docs). It is certainly possible that things in Core Data could do the same. But again, if should never matter to you except for performance considerations (i.e. the data may need to be recalculated).

Of course you may lose your entire in-memory data store when your application is killed, which can happen anytime. But the OS doesn't just remove memory from you arbitrarily.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I guess what I am most concerned with here, is if it is possible for data in core data to be lost during a background state, or when in low memory situations, presumably its necessary to use some type of recovery technique? Though I cant find anything on this subject on my google searches. This seems to hint, either all the data is lost and the app closes (which in my case is fine because the data can be redownloaded on a fresh launch), or the app keeps the data while in 'background mode' making it immediately available for use when the app becomes active.

Comment: Yes; you will either be killed, or your non-purgeable memory will be left alone (unless you're explicitly creating purgeable memory, see NSPurgeableData, that means everything). The system will not throw away "some" of your memory, and will only throw it away by killing you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% but I would have to say no, this would not be reclaimed partially and this is why. iOS will allocate the memory used and not deallocate unless a memory warning was reached and in that event it would simply close the app all together or be handled by you. Processes will halt after 10 minutes and all resources held by that sandboxed app will remain in memory unless needed and in that event the app as a whole would close. So, if another app requests more memory than what's available, your app and it's allocated memory will close but bits and pieces will not close (your datasource).